# SQL Update error. FK Conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to change the name of a group from ASSY to Manufacturing but am running into some dificulties. It is on a sql server database. I ran the query below.

```
 Update groups
 set  group_code= 'Manufacturing'
 where site_code = 'TMMBC' and group_code = 'ASSY' and group_description  = 'Manufacturing'
```

But it returned with this error - "The UPDATE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "user_groups_FK_2". The conflict occurred in database "eci", table "dbo.user_groups"."

Is there a way I can update both tables at the same time to bypass this error?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way I can update both tables at the same time to bypass
>   this error?

Yes. You can define the foreign key to cascade on update.

I would consider restructuring it so that `groups` has an integer surrogate key though and have the textual description as a separate column.

This avoids having to repeat the relatively long string `Manufacturing` possibly many times in the child table.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your definition for table user_groups looks something like:

```
create table dbo.user_groups (
    group_code varchar(100),
    -- other fields
    constraint user_groups_fk_2 foreign key (group_code) references dbo.groups (group_code)
);
```

You would change the table definition to have the foreign key cascade, like:

```
create table dbo.user_groups (
    group_code varchar(100),
    -- other fields
    constraint user_groups_fk_2 foreign key (group_code) references dbo.groups (group_code) on delete cascade on update cascade
);
```

Or through ALTER TABLE statements:

```
alter table dbo.user_groups drop constraint user_groups_fk_2;

alter table dbo.user_groups add constraint user_groups_fk_2 foreign key (group_code) references dbo.groups (group_code) on delete cascade on update cascade;
```